# Relation (approximate??) between Swap rate and Cap strike

Tags: interest-rate-swap, caplet

I just have come across some relation between `Interest rate swap` and strike of `Cap` as below

$K_{Cap Strike} = \frac{1}{1 + r \times \left(T_2 - T_1 \right)}$

Where $r$ is the Swap rate and the `caplet` is defined between time interval $\left[T_2, T_1 \right]$

I wonder if above relation is technically valid and if it is some approximate relation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It never hurts to name a source.

Comment: @AKdemy - Sure, it is https://cvacentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/4E-Chapter-15A.xlsm (sheet 15.5). Here you see that `rate` is an input, which appears to be 'swap-rate'. This input is used to generate exposure for `Cap` with a strike based on the formula that I posted.

Comment: That is a very specific use case (HW1F MC for EPE and ENE). A cap itself, being an OTC product can have any strike you desire.

Comment: I agree. However looking at the specific equation for relation between `strike` of `caplet` and `swap-rate`, it appears that there definitely be some reason and purpose for it.